# How do I know what other npm projects that my current npm project is linked to?

Tags: linux, npm, devops

I'm working on project1, project2 both, and project1 is linked to project2 on my local(project1 --> project2) using `npm link`.

How do I know that project1 is linked successfully to project2?

I have being using `npm -g ls --depth=0 --link=true`, but that's not exactly what I want, the command only should what symlink is created to the npm global node_module folder but not should the "linked relations between two projects".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no built-in npm command to determine which project/package(s) have been linked to another project/package via the [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) command.

However, you can install and utilize the [link-status](https://github.com/danmakenoise/link-status) package:

1. Firstly, install the `link-status` package by running the following command:

   ```
   npm install -g link-status
   ```
2. Then `cd` to your project directory (i.e. *Project2*) and run the following command:

   ```
   link-status
   ```

   it should then log the name(s) of each project/package(s) that is symlinked. For instance:

   > `project1`
3. You can also utilize the `-s` option. For example, if you run the following command from inside the *Project2* directory:

   ```
   link-status -s
   ```

   it will additionally log the path to each linked package. E.g.

   > ```
   > project1
   >   ╚═══ ../../some/path/to/node_modules/project1
   > ```